# A surface of revolution, why or why not?

Tags: calculus

I found the rectangular equation and know I have a sphere with center ( 0, 0, 2) and radius 2. I am not sure how else to describe a sphere besides center and radius or how to determine if it is a surface of revolution. Thank you for any help!

Comment: This is very unclear... How to represent a sphere... How about $x^2 + y^2 + (z-2)^2 = 2^2$?  As a surface of revolution?  How about $x^2 + z^2 = 4z$ revolved around the z axis?

Comment: I apologize. That is the equation I got and it literally just asks is it a surface of revolution? And I just figured it could be if it were revolved around something so I didn't know why it couldn't be. I could use that revolved around the z axis. Thank you!